How I can Hydrate a Laravel Model with its children when I create Both of them?
In a laravel project I do:
$childValues = [1,3,4,5];
$model = MyModel::create(['value'=>1.2]);

$modelChildValues=[];
foreach($childValues as $value){
  $modelChildValues[]=ModelChild::create(['parent_id'=>$model->id,'value'=>$value]);
}

$reource = new MyModelResource($model);

And I have a resource where I serialize my Model:
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class MyModelResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {

        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'value'=>$this->value,
            'children' => ModelChildResource::collection($this->children)
        ];
    }
}

And one for the child:
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class ModelChildResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {

        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'value'=>$this->value,
        ];
    }
}

As you can see I create both a model with child elements in one go then I create a resource. The MyModel model is:
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class MyModel extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ModelChild::class,'child_id','id');
    }
}


And simiraly is ModelChild one:
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class MyModel extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected function mymodel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Model::class,'id','child_id');
    }
}


My question is how I can hydrate the model in $model with $modelChildValues so I can avoid selecting for inserted models?

When you call $model->children()->create(), you don't need 'parent_id' => $model->id; that is implied via $model->children(). You can then simply call $model->load('children') (or $model->load(['children' => function ($query) use ($childValues) { return $query->whereIn('value', $childValues); }]); to only load the ones you created). You seem to be trying to avoid a single additional query to load these records from the DB, which isn't really a performance bottleneck... ->create() returns the instance, but doesn't automatically assign it to $model->children; you need to do that.

You can use methods like setRelation to manually attach one or more models
$childValues = [1,3,4,5];
$model = MyModel::create(['value'=>1.2]);

$children = collect([]);
foreach($childValues as $value) {
  // the relation field will be auto filled
  $children->push($model->children()->create(['value' => $value]));
}

$model->setRelation('children', $children);

$reource = new MyModelResource($model);


But wint $model->children()->create(['value' => $value]) autmatically create a child to the model??? Why setRelation is also required?

@DimitriosDesyllas no, create performs an insert query on your DB and returns the created model. Now your model is loaded in memory and you can decide what to do with it. Keep in mind that $model might have more children, than the ones you created in this method and this way you attach only the ones you created during this specific method call.
